# Render Inversion template from hash

Tags: ruby, inversion

Is it possible to render an Inversion template from a hash? And if not, how does one construct a complex template corresponding to a hash such as:

```
{ :a => [ { :b => 'foo', :c => 'bar' }, { :d => 'blah', :e => 'blubb'} ] }
```

Unfortunately the user guide doesn't show such examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you want to render the hash. Assuming the code:

```
require 'inversion'

the_hash = { :a => [
    { :b => 'foo', :c => 'bar' },
    { :d => 'blah', :e => 'blubb'}
  ] }
```

You can render it as-is, of course:

```
<!-- prettyprint.tmpl -->
<code><?pp the_hash ?></code>
```

and then:

```
tmpl = Inversion::Template.load( 'prettyprint.tmpl' )
tmpl.the_hash = the_hash
puts tmpl.render
```

which will render as:

```
<!-- prettyprint.tmpl -->
<code>{:a=&gt;[{:b=&gt;"foo", :c=&gt;"bar"}, {:d=&gt;"blah", :e=&gt;"blubb"}]}</code>
```

Assuming you want to do something more complex with the hash, like render some of its members:

```
<!-- members.tmpl -->
A's first B is: <?call the_hash[:a].first[:b] ?> 
A's first C is: <?call the_hash[:a].first[:c] ?> 
A's second D is: <?call the_hash[:a][1][:d] ?>   
A's second E is: <?call the_hash[:a][1][:e] ?>
```

which (with the same code as the previous example except loading 'members.tmpl' instead) will render like so:

```
<!-- members.tmpl -->
A's first B is: foo 
A's first C is: bar 
A's second D is: blah   
A's second E is: blubb
```

But building a big complex data structure like your hash, and then later merging it with a template is not really how Inversion is intended to be used. The idea is really that loading the template gives you a Ruby object with an API, suitable for passing around and incrementally adding stuff to before rendering it. Instead of building a hash, just pass the template object itself around and call accessors on it, then let it pull out what it needs to build the view:

```
tmpl.users = User.all
tmpl.company = "ACME Widgets, Pty"
tmpl.render
```

This also has the advantage of being more amenable to mocking:

```
# (rspec)
tmpl = mock( "members template" )
tmpl.should_receive( :users ).with( User.all )
tmpl.should_receive( :company ).with( company_name )
tmpl.should_receive( :render ).and_return( "the rendered stuff" )
```

This removes the template contents from the test entirely, and just focuses on what messages the controller should be sending to the view.

There's a fairly full-featured example [in the manual](http://deveiate.org/code/Inversion-manual/examples.html), along with [the code that renders it](https://github.com/ged/inversion/blob/master/experiments/demo.rb).

The library (and its documentation) are fairly new, so thanks for bringing this up. I have a pending patch to merge [the manual](http://deveiate.org/code/Inversion-manual/) with the API docs, which should help, but in the meantime it's probably the best place to find examples.

Hope this helps. I'm happy to answer more in-depth questions personally (ged at FaerieMUD.org), or accept patches via pull request on [Github](https://github.com/ged/inversion) or [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/ged/inversion).